# Is there a service in aws, that shows all permissions denied due to wrong configurations

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions

Is there a aws service, that shows all permissions denied errors for each service?

Comment: CloudTrail for management API requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [What Is AWS CloudTrail?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html):

> AWS CloudTrail is an AWS service that helps you enable operational and risk auditing, governance, and compliance of your AWS account. Actions taken by a user, role, or an AWS service are **recorded as events in CloudTrail**. Events include actions taken in the AWS Management Console, AWS Command Line Interface, and AWS SDKs and APIs.
>
> CloudTrail is enabled on your AWS account when you create it. When activity occurs in your AWS account, that activity is recorded in a CloudTrail event. You can easily **view recent events** in the CloudTrail console by going to Event history. For an ongoing record of activity and events in your AWS account, create an event data store or create a trail.
>
> Visibility into your AWS account activity is a key aspect of security and operational best practices. You can use CloudTrail to view, search, download, archive, analyze, and respond to account activity across your AWS infrastructure. You can **identify who or what took which action, what resources were acted upon, when the event occurred**, and other details to help you analyze and respond to activity in your AWS account. Optionally, you can enable AWS CloudTrail Insights on a trail to help you identify and respond to unusual activity.

All requests to AWS services are made via API calls, including requests sent from the console, AWS CLI or programmatic API. CloudTrail records the time, request, IP address and **whether the API call was successful**. It therefore also contains a list of requests that were denied due to permission errors.

Please note that the default Trail is only kept for 90 days. If you wish to retain the Trails for longer periods, you will need to configure your own Trail.